# CSS - nth type selector for 2 different class elements

Tags: css

What is the proper way to ignore 2 different .section elements, using nth type.  this is what I have.

```
.section:not(:nth-of-type(1)),
.section:not(:nth-of-type(11)) {
 max-width:900px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Please expand on what "doesn't work" means. Post a complete code example and what you're expecting.

Comment: i updated my original question - sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your selector is that it selects all `.section` elements which are not the first of type, and also the `.section` elements which are not the 11th of type. So you end up selecting all `.section` elements.

Instead, I think you want

```
.section:not(:nth-of-type(1)):not(:nth-of-type(11)) {
    max-width:900px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

That is, select the `.section` which are not the first of type nor the 11th of type.

```css
.section:not(:nth-of-type(1)):not(:nth-of-type(11)){
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">1</div>
<div class="section">2</div>
<div class="section">3</div>
<div class="section">4</div>
<div class="section">5</div>
<div class="section">6</div>
<div class="section">7</div>
<div class="section">8</div>
<div class="section">9</div>
<div class="section">10</div>
<div class="section">11</div>
<div class="section">12</div>
<div class="section">13</div>
<div class="section">14</div>
<div class="section">15</div>
```

Comment: your update worked for me.  Yes this allows me to ignore 2 different .section class elements.  thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think the typical approach to this is to specify a CSS rule that affects everything and a more specific rule that affects these particular elements.

```
.section {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.section:nth-of-type(10n + 1) {
  max-width: auto;
  margin: auto;
}
```

The `.section:nth-of-type(10n + 1)` will target not just the 1st and 11th items, but also the 21st, 31st, etc., items, anticipating the possibility of more items.

Comment: Or, if only the 1st and 11th items should be matched, `:nth-of-type(-10n+11)` can be used instead of `:nth-of-type(10n+1)`. And note the initial values of [`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width) and [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) are `none` and `0` (respectively), not `auto`. There is also the [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) keyword.

Comment: @Oriol Thanks. I'd realized looking at it later that `auto` may not be the appropriate setting. Would `initial` actually be correct, since `.section` could refer to any HTML element?